# write string in file if not exist java

Tags: java, file, file-io

i try to write String to file only if String not exist, this is my code

```
File rule_file = new File("test_rules.rules");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(rule_file);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(rule_file,true));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!rule_write.equals(lineFromFile))
            {
               if(unique.get(nilai_besar).getCount()>10)
               {
                        writer.write(rule_write);
                        writer.close();
                        break;
               }
            }
        }
```

but, the program keep write String to file even the String already exist in file.
Please help, thanks...

Comment: nextLine() reads lines of text.  Howe are you writing lines of text.  Is the newline in the String itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every line that is not equal you (potentially) try to write to the file.

What you want is to write to the file if **all** lines are not equal:

```
    boolean found = false;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (rule_write.equals(lineFromFile))
        {
           found = true;
           break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        // append rule_write to the file
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could be writing the extra line after checking just one line of the file.

I suggest you read the file to the end, without attempting to write to it, until you know the line does appear anywhere in the file.

i.e. I would use a PrintWriter.println() and I would move all the code for writing to after the search loop.

Answer (score 0):

Go with `indexOf()` or `contains()` instead of equals() and equalsIgnoreCase(),

I am sure that the line you read may contain

- Empty spaces (before or after)
- Next line problem may occur

If you use `indexOf()` or `contains()` , it will check ,whether the line have the string (`rule_write`)

Make sure the the values are coming  in `while()`